# How to call Typescript method from Javascript callback method - Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular2 my issue is that I am not able to call component method from javascript callback here is the code snippet.

```
 declare var CORE_FACTORY:any;

 // CORE_FACTORY Defined in javascript file which I've included in index.html and it's gets loded perfectly.

 let coreApi = CORE_FACTORY.setupApiByDomain(Domain.QA); 
 coreApi.addUserEventListener(apiName, ApiEvent.ON_ANY_EVENT,this._userCallBack);
 coreApi.callApi(request, this.afterCallApi);

 afterCallApi(status, responceObject) {
            this.postCreateInstrument(accountNumber); //Getting error right here.
 }

 public postCreateInstrument(accountNumber:string) {
         alert('test');
 }
```

Comment: It's all JavaScript in the end; TypeScript compiles (technically, transpiles) to JavaScript before the browser interprets it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to access global `this` is to use `bind` like this:

```
coreApi.callApi(request, this.afterCallApi.bind(this, status, responceObject));
```

Right now this piece of js code  `coreApi.callApi(request, this.afterCallApi);` as you know will call `this.afterCallApi` but note that you are using the function without paranthesis () this means that `this.afterCallApi` will be invoked as an inner function of `callApi`, with `callApi`'s inner `this` binded to `afterCallApi`.

If you want to test it, do a `console.log(this);` inside `afterCallApi` with your original code. You will see that `this` is an object and not the global`this`.

In order to give the "access" to `afterCallApi` we simply `bind` the `this` which refers to the global `this`.

Also check this great post for more info: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

If you define your function using the arrow format, it will maintain the scope of `this` for you.

Example:

```
var afterCallApi = (status, response) => { this.postCreateInstrument(accountNumber); }
```